# pass clicks throught transparent uiwebview

Tags: uiwebview, transparent

I have a uiwebview overlayed in front of another project (actually a unity3d project).

I made the uiwebview transparent. Is there a setting to pass clicks through uiwebview to the buttons beneath the webview overlay?